# How do I test if a stream has ended?

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I have a stream that may or may not have already ended. If it has ended, I don't want to sit there forever waiting for the `end` event. How do I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of node 12.9.0, readable streams have a `readableEnded` property you can check – see [`readable.readableEnded` in the Stream documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_readableended).

(Writable streams have a [corresponding property](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_writableended))

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely have to, you can check `stream._readableState.ended`, at least in node 0.10 and 0.12. This isn't public API though so be careful. Also apparently all streams aren't guarantee to have this property too:

Worth reading on this:

https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2368

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/445

Answer (score 3):

You probably shouldn't check, and instead attach an `end` event listener.  When the stream ends you will get an `end` event.

If a [readable]stream is implemented correctly, you will get an end event when there is nothing left to read.  For open-ended streams that don't end, you could implement an activity timer to see how long it's been since the stream was last readable, and decide after a certain amount of time to remove your listeners.

```
(function() {
    var timeout = null;
    var WAIT_TIME = 10 * 1000; // 10 Sec
    function stopListening( ) {
        stream.off('data', listener);
    }
    function listener( data ) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(stopListening, WAIT_TIME);
        // DO STUFF
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(stopListening, WAIT_TIME);
    stream.on('data', listener);
})();
```

Comment: I don't have access to the stream until after the `end` event has fired

Comment: You can pipe your input stream in a new stream.Readable, and attach your listeners to the wrapper.  Then you don't have to worry about whether it has data or not, you just attach event handlers to handle both instances.